# I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed on my laptop. How can I install Windows 8.1 alongside?

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed on my laptop. How can I install Windows 8.1 alongside?
Can I dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows after Ubuntu is not the recommended process for a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu system, but it is possible.

For more information see
[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

But I would recommend you to install windows first and after that Ubuntu. I
t worked perfect for me.

If you decide so, try this step-by-step:
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html
(It is for 14.04, but it doesn't matter)